# How to alter the DynamoDb table name based on stable and unstable environments?

Tags: kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, kotlin-multiplatform

I have two different table names, Employee and EmployeeUntsble. I want to use the Employee table when the environment is stable and EmployeeUntsble when the environment is unstable.

Right now, my code is working only for one table. Here is how I implemented it.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Employee")
    data class Employee(
     @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
     var id: String = "",
     @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
     var name: String? = null,
    )
```

How to use the Employee class for both tables based on different environments?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the [v2 SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb-enhanced), you will get a better way of interaction with the DB.

```java
@DynamoDbBean
data class Employee(
   @DynamoDbPartitionKey
   var id: String = "",
   var name: String? = null
```

then to interact you use

```
    var table = enhancedClient.table(
            <table name from property>,
            TableSchema.fromClass(Employee.class));
```

the table name can be stored in a env specific property and you can have one for stable and one for unstable